# Selenium Error?

Tags: php, selenium

I'm rather new to silenium and just trying to get basics working via API, however when I request the following

```
$post =array('desiredCapabilities' => array(
    'browserName' => 'firefox',
    'version' => '',
    'platform' => 'WINDOWS',
    'javascriptEnabled' => 1,
    'takesScreenshot' => 1,
    'locationContextEnabled' => 1,
    'cssSelectorsEnabled' => 1,
    'acceptSslCerts' => 1 
    ));
```

It returns an error

```
  [sessionId] => 
[status] => 13
[value] => stdClass Object
    (
        [message] => java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        [suppressed] => Array
            (
            )

        [localizedMessage] => java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        [cause] => 
        [class] => java.lang.ClassCastException
        [hCode] => 1893316977
        [stackTrace] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => FirefoxDriver.java
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => 114
                        [className] => org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => extractProfile
                        [hCode] => -1033096603
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => FirefoxDriver.java
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => 87
                        [className] => org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => 
                        [hCode] => 2005391444
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -2
                        [className] => sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
                        [nativeMethod] => 1
                        [methodName] => newInstance0
                        [hCode] => 513928194
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => newInstance
                        [hCode] => -432498851
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => newInstance
                        [hCode] => -2147429624
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => java.lang.reflect.Constructor
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => newInstance
                        [hCode] => -1851634561
                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => DefaultDriverFactory.java
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => 63
                        [className] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => callConstructor
                        [hCode] => -368088126
                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => DefaultDriverFactory.java
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => 57
                        [className] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => newInstance
                        [hCode] => -1365021419
                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => DefaultSession.java
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => 177
                        [className] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => call
                        [hCode] => 2056168426
                    )

                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => DefaultSession.java
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => 1
                        [className] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => call
                        [hCode] => 2056168250
                    )

                [10] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => innerRun
                        [hCode] => 1144956884
                    )

                [11] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => run
                        [hCode] => 424519275
                    )

                [12] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => runWorker
                        [hCode] => -1208971944
                    )

                [13] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => run
                        [hCode] => -166011880
                    )

                [14] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fileName] => 
                        [class] => java.lang.StackTraceElement
                        [lineNumber] => -1
                        [className] => java.lang.Thread
                        [nativeMethod] => 
                        [methodName] => run
                        [hCode] => 1432591020
                    )

            )

    )

[class] => org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response
[hCode] => 1713234840
```

I have next to no experience in java, anyone could give me a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the Selenium RC source code you'll see that line 144 in FirefoxDriver.java reads:

```
Boolean acceptCerts = (Boolean) capabilities.getCapability(ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS);
```

So you probably need to pass:
    acceptSslCerts => true instead of acceptSslCerts => 1

Comment: Prolly also the other semi-obvious booleans in that list: javascriptEnabled, takesScreenshot, locationContextEnabled, and cssSelectorsEnabled.